# Ionic app capable of creating a wifi hotspot and data transfer to the devices

Tags: ionic2

I want to create a ionic 2 app, which should be able to create a wifi hotspot and transfer data to the devices which are connected to the hotspot.
Hotspot creation part is done.. But i don't know how to do the data transfer thing.
Any tutorials to follow?

Answer (score 2):

Hosting a server from an Ionic app seems like a terrible idea. Are you trying to make a app that is a server?

But it seems there's a Cordova plugin for that. [If you're really determined, maybe you can slot into that](https://github.com/jxcore/jxcore-cordova#how-to-install-node-modules)

Comment: I don't know whether this is gonna work or not.
What i'm going to do is.. Create a wifi hotspot with the application. And i want to share data with the devices which are connected to the hotspot.. How to do this?